# Visual Studio Code only runs python scripts in debugging mode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Under Windows 10, Visual Studio Code 1.33, after an update, can no longer run a python without debugging (scripts run fine with debugging though!).

I have reinstalled VSC and Python (3.7), the issue continues just the same. The interpreter works fine from command line.

The following command returns nothing after a couple of seconds (note the `--nodebug` switch):

```
PS C:\Users\folder\daily_graph> cd 'c:\Users\folder\daily_graph'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--nodebug' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '55110' 'c:\Users\folder\daily_graph.py'
```

On the other hand, the following runs just fine (with the debugger - the `--nodebug` switch is gone), making my charts:

```
PS C:\Users\folder\daily_graph> cd 'c:\Users\folder\daily_graph'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' '55114' 'c:\Users\folder\daily_graph.py'
```

Since I'm not getting any errors on output, I can't work out what's wrong with the setup. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there is a bug somewhere in
ms-python.python-2019.3.6558/pythonFiles/lib/python/ptvsd

this version does not take care of the 'redirectOutput' settings in the configuration used in the the launch.json. when launched as ^F5 (run)

The "redirectOutput": true is ok for a "console": "externalTerminal"
but for a "console": "internalTerminal", the redirection is not done.

The only possible answer is "wait for a new ms-python extension version".

Ps the bug is also visible on vscode on a mac too.

Comment: Hi Olivier - do you know if there is a bug reported on GitHub for this? If so, you could add it to your answer and I will mark as answered.

Answer (score -1):

Be in the folder with the file you want to run, then write

```
python filname.py
```

remember to save the file before you run.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @JanniJensenDahm - I mentioned that the interpreter runs fine from command line. I would like it to work properly within VSC under 'Start without debugging' too...